# Command "webpack-dev-server" not found with rails 6 and docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpack

I have a rails 6 app. I just did rails new to generate it, nothing else.

These is my docker file:

```
ARG RUBY_VERSION
# See explanation below
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG YARN_VERSION

# Add PostgreSQL to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Add NodeJS to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install dependencies
# We use an external Aptfile for that, stay tuned
COPY ./dockerDev/Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    nodejs \
    yarn=$YARN_VERSION-1 \
    $(cat /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Configure bundler and PATH
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
  BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH /app/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

# Upgrade RubyGems and install required Bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION

# Create a directory for the app code
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app
# RUN rails webpacker:install

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts. Fixes a Rails-specific issue that prevents the server from restarting when a certain server.pid file pre-exists
# COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
# RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

And this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.3'
        PG_MAJOR: '10'
        NODE_MAJOR: '11'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.13.0'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.0.2'
    image: my-dev:1.0.0
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      # !!!! WARNING !!! For MacOs add this line. It does have a cost though
      # https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#cached
      # - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
      - ./dockerDev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      # - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@postgres
      - BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR=/bundle/bootsnap
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      - HISTFILE=/app/log/.bash_history
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/app/log/.psql_history
      - EDITOR=vi
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      # - redis

  # runner:
  #   <<: *backend
  #   command: /bin/bash
  #   ports:
  #     - '3000:3000'
  #     - '3002:3002'

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3054 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    ports:
      - '3054:3054'

  # sidekiq:
  #   <<: *backend
  #   command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.10
    volumes:
      - .psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
    environment:
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/root/log/.psql_history
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  # redis:
  #   image: redis:3.2-alpine
  #   volumes:
  #     - redis:/data
  #   ports:
  #     - 6379

  webpacker:
    <<: *app
    command: ["/bin/bash","-c", "./bin/webpack-dev-server"]
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development}
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  # redis:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
  packs:
```

On another computer I have ran rails webpacker:install so I have the followin file in `bin` folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
ENV["NODE_ENV"]  ||= "development"

require "pathname"
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

require "webpacker"
require "webpacker/dev_server_runner"

APP_ROOT = File.expand_path("..", __dir__)
Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT) do
  Webpacker::DevServerRunner.run(ARGV)
end
```

This setup works on the laptop that did the webpacker:install, however on any new laptop it generates the following error:

```
webpacker_1  | yarn run v1.13.0
webpacker_1  | error Command "webpack-dev-server" not found.
webpacker_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any idea why? Since the file is clearly in that folder?

```
root@11b6f5f161d1:/app# ruby ./bin/webpack-dev-server
Traceback (most recent call last):
    7: from ./bin/webpack-dev-server:17:in `<main>'
    6: from ./bin/webpack-dev-server:17:in `chdir'
    5: from ./bin/webpack-dev-server:18:in `block in <main>'
    4: from /bundle/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'
    3: from /bundle/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:11:in `run'
    2: from /bundle/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:38:in `detect_port!'
    1: from /bundle/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:38:in `new'
/bundle/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:38:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
```

Update for David:

```
root@b6f1fb4ad240:/app/bin# ls
rails  rake  setup  webpack  webpack-dev-server  yarn
```

Comment: How sure are you that those files are there?  When you mount a named volume into a container you’re telling Docker that directory contains vital user data that it should never ever overwrite, and it’s very easy for one of those volumes to be out of date.

Comment: @DavidMaze

Very sure, I just started the container with a different command to check if they are truly there. Check update on answer

Answer (score 3):

Verifies that already installed files in **node_modules** did not get removed by running `yarn install --check-files` if you use yarn and start `bin/webpack-dev-server` back